# Javascript breakline in msgwindow document write

Tags: javascript, html

So I am doing basic things here. I am opening a javascript MsgWindow here and pushing data from an array to the window using document.write. Initially, I am pushing the array data to a variable, I am breaking the line before sending to the variable using "\n". but when the window opens, its all mixed together. How do I get a line break in the window like I see in the console?

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=800,height=800");
myWindow.document.write(arr2);
```

here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jaisil007/o798zdos/

Comment: You need to remember that browser windows process spaces and newlines characters as 1 space. It would be best to enclose the document in a tag such as a <div> and then use the <br> tag for new lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a line break add the br tag to your string instead

```
var arr2="";
arr.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    var data= element;
    var stringData = data.toString()

    var stringDataToString = stringData.toString();
    arr2 += stringDataToString+ "<br>";
}
```

You need to remember that browser windows process spaces and newlines characters etc. as 1 space. It would be best to enclose the document in a tag such as a < div > and then use the 
    < br  >
 tag for new lines

Answer (score 0):

In link 214 on your code, change this: `arr2 += stringDataToString + "\n";`

For this: `arr2 += stringDataToString + "<br>";`

https://jsfiddle.net/o798zdos/1/